# ¿Porque debo logearme dos veces en login laravel jetstream?

Tags: php, laravel, login, laravel-jetstream

resulta que intento logearme (estoy usando laravel jetstream) y la primera vez al intentar logearme ,se resetean los campos, y no me logea,pero la segunda vez cuando me logeo me reedirige a la ruta deseada, es molesto tener que logearme 2 veces,porque sucede esto y como podría solucionarlo?,gracias!

Imagen Login :
[image: img]

```php
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

              
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Provider RouteServiceProvider:

```php
    public const HOME = '/dashboard';
```

Si se necesita mas contexto,estoy atento!

Comment: El código que pones lo has modificado tu? Porque el login viene super bien configurado en Jetstream...

Comment: @OCHOA La verdad solo he modificado la variable home, a otro valor diferente al dashboard, pero luego nuevamente puse el nombre dashboard ya que hay al final quise que me rediriga , pero en torno a cambios de redireccion realmente no :(

Comment: @OCHOA Aunque hay veces que me permitel logearme de inmediato,es raro...